# perl, starting more processes at the same time

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

I am using Strawberry Perl on Windows XP to download multiple html pages, I want each in a variable.

Right now I am doing this, but as I see it, it gets one page at a time:

```
my $page = `curl -s http://mysite.com/page -m 2`;
my $page2 = `curl -s http://myothersite.com/page -m 2`;
```

I looked into Parallel::ForkManager, but couldnt get it to work.
Also tried to use the windows command `start` before `curl` but that doesn't get the page.

Is there a more simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to limit the number of children at a time?

Comment: Do you know the list of URLs before you start downloading the first one, or do you discover new URLs as you download?

Answer (score 3):

The [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) module should work for you, but because it uses `fork` instead of threads, the variables in the parent and each of the child processses is separate and they must communicate a different way.

This program uses the `-o` option of `curl` to save the pages in files. The file for, say, `http://mysite.com/page` is saved in file `http\mysite.com\page` and can be retrieved from there by the parent process.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Parallel::ForkManager;
use URI;
use File::Spec;
use File::Path 'make_path';

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);

foreach my $site (qw( http://mysite.com/page http://myothersite.com/page )) {
  my $pid = $pm->start;
  next if $pid;
  fetch($site);
  $pm->finish;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;

sub fetch {
  my ($url) = @_;

  my $uri = URI->new($url);
  my $filename = File::Spec->catfile($uri->scheme, $uri->host, $uri->path);
  my ($vol, $dir, $file) = File::Spec->splitpath($filename);

  make_path $dir;
  print `curl http://mysite.com/page -m 2 -o $filename`;
}
```

---

**Update**

Here is a version that uses [`threads`](https://metacpan.org/module/threads) with [`threads::shared`](https://metacpan.org/module/threads%3a%3ashared) to return each page into a hash shared between all the threads. The hash must be marked as shared, and locked before it is modified to prevent concurrent access.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %pages;
my @threads;

share %pages;

foreach my $site (qw( http://mysite.com/page http://myothersite.com/page )) {
  my $thread = threads->new('fetch', $site);
  push @threads, $thread;
}

$_->join for @threads;

for (scalar keys %pages) {
  printf "%d %s fetched\n", $_, $_ == 1 ? 'page' : 'pages';
}

sub fetch {
  my ($url) = @_;
  my $page = `curl -s $url -m 2`;
  lock %pages;
  $pages{$url} = $page;
}
```

Comment: on windows, Thread::Pool may be a better solution than emulated fork.

Comment: Yes, forking does not work well on widows at all (at least not in the times that I've tried it).

Comment: @ysth: I'm never sure of the status of `fork` on Windows. In addition to the problem with sharing variables, that's why I added a solution using `threads`. I don't really see and advantage with `Thread::Pool` over the standard pragma.

Comment: the advantage is limiting the number of concurrent threads, same as the advantage you take in P::FM over just a bunch of forks